# Which scala collection is best for constructing a resource pool

Tags: scala, concurrency, scala-collections

I'd like to create a shared resource pool which could be accessed by multiple thread concurrently.

Each thread will do something like:

1. fetch a resource from the pool (if no resource available, do something else)
2. do something with the fetched resource
3. return the resource back to the pool.

In java, probably I will go with ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Is there any better option in scala?

Answer (score 1):

Scala runs on Java so you could just continue using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  If it works for you, why mess with it?

Comment: Sometimes, scala providers nicer alternatives to java concurrent collections, that's why.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Otherwise, scala guys won't create TrieMap since we already have ConcurrentHashMap :) I'm just seeking whether there could be a very simple lightweight lock-free solution in scala.